# Groovy setProperty not working in different classes with IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

The standard example form the groovy documentation does not work if i separate the class into an other file. Both next to each other work fine.

```
//File: Expandable.groovy
class Expandable {
    def storage = [:]
    def getProperty(String name) { storage[name] }
    void setProperty(String name, value) { storage[name] = value }
}

//File: Main.groovy  
def e = new Expandable()
e.foo = "bar"
println e.foo
```

Exception

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo for class: Expandable
```

Comment: What version of Groovy? How are you running it? Just saving those 2 files and running `groovy Main.groovy` works for me.

Comment: That is good to know that it works else where. I was running it with Java 7u45 Groovy 2.2.1 and IntelliJ 13.0 Community. Your hint brought me to try eclipse again and it worked. I dont have time to investigate the cause. Anaway, a bit disappointed from IntelliJ. Thanks Tim

Comment: I've created an issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117982

Comment: Were you able to reproduce? Appreciate your quick reaction!